# Trouble on comparing arrays items

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand why my comparison between arrays items always return true. How can I check if different items in the same array are not equal?

I tried `!=`, `!==`, and `!colCheck[i].equals(colCheck[x])` but it did not work.

```
function mergeCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rowsToMerge = [];
  var colCheck = sheet.getRange(8,10,79,1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < 79; i++) {
    var x = i + 1;
    if (colCheck[i] != colCheck[x]) rowsToMerge.push(i);// Always returns true
    if (colCheck[i] == '') {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the arrays items and even when they are exactly the same, the comparison returns true.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproductible example ?

Comment: try using `!==` and `===` istead of `!=` and `==`, also avoid magic numbers like 79, you can use `forEach` instead of `for`
More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: what do you store in `colCheck`? objects of which type?

Answer (score 2):

Elements of colCheck are objects, so comparing with `==`, `!=`, `===`, or `!===` just compares references which is probably not what you intend, try comparing object properties instead.